# Getting NPE when trying write to file using BufferedWriter.What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, binary-tree

I have a tree setup. I am trying to save it into a txt file using a BufferedWriter. It creates the file, then it runs into a null pointer exception when my program first calls the write method of the BufferedReader(line 102), so I guess its not getting initialized properly? Note: "node" is just the payload of the root, I can print the tree using the same method, so the issue is not with the node variable.

```
public class TreeNode {
    File file;
    BufferedWriter writer;
    FileWriter fw;

    public void save() /// save tree into txt file
    {

        try 
        {
            file = new File("save.txt");
            if(!file.exists())
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            fw = new FileWriter(file);
            writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            print();

        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void print() {
        try 
        {
            writer.write(node); //line 102
            writer.newLine();
            if (no != null) 
            {
                no.print();
                writer.newLine();
            }
            if (yes != null) 
            {
                yes.print();
                writer.newLine();
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
}
```

Error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TreeNode.print(TreeNode.java:102)
    at TreeNode.print(TreeNode.java:106)
    at TreeNode.save(TreeNode.java:90)
    at TreeNode.playagain(TreeNode.java:59)
    at TreeNode.go(TreeNode.java:189)
    at CelebrityGame.main(CelebrityGame.java:22)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It looks like you're not calling `save()` before `print()` and so `writer` has not been initialised.

Comment: I have read it, together with some other questions. I debugged my code, I know my "writer" is null, but I dont understand why. In your link it says:
"If you tried to debug the problem and still don't have a solution, you can post a question for more help, but make sure to include what you've tried so far. At a minimum, include the stacktrace in the question, and mark the important line numbers in the code. Also, try simplifying the code first (see SSCCE)." And thats what I did.

Comment: You got an exception opening the file writer and carried on as though it hadn't  happened, so `writer` was still null. Poorly structured exception handling. Don't write code like this. NB you don't need the exists/createNewFile part. It's just a waste of time and space. The OS already does all that when you create the file writer. You're just doubling the processing.

Comment: @eckes node is a string defined with a constructor. But it is not null, i can print the tree to the console with the same recursive method. I am not using "writer" anywhere else than in the code that i included here. I will try to rewrite the methods differently.

Comment: BTW: you dont need the crateNewFile(), FileWriter will do that automatically.

Comment: @EJP not sure if any of the writer methods throw an exception then print() will not be called, it is inside the same try.

Comment: It is not inside the same try. Creating file writer is inside a try of its own. That's the problem.

Comment: Then you have a different code then I have, I see `writer = new BufferedWriter(fw); print();` right next to each other.

Comment: BTW: since you cannot call print() from outside save() I would not make it public but private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that you have more than one `TreeNode` instance, but only the outer one has `writer` filled.

You can see in your stack trace that actually the outer writer was successfuly progressing to line 106, where it calls `no.print()`. This is another node object. And in this object it was then failing in line 102, because there the writer was null.

It is better if you remove the `writer` from the fields and pass it as an argument to print() and don't store the other variables as fields (`file` + `fw`) either).

Comment: As a quick test that I am right, make "writer" static, but dont keep this as a final solution.

Comment: you are right, making it static worked. Could you please explain why? Anyways, thank you, I will rewrite my code following your suggestion.

Comment: The explanation is in the second paragraph.